# Will apt-get install replace old version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ld

I need the linker `ld` which is in the `binutils` package.
But the server I work remotely on has already an `ld` version but it is too old.

If I do

```
sudo apt-get install binutils
```

will this replace the old one and possibly mess up with other users who need this old version ?

If yes, how do I get a `ld` just for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will update ld for all users sharing the same standart /bin and /usr/bin, unless they're living in `chroot`, then it will not affect them at all.

You can take updated binary and put in another place (which should be in your `PATH`), so you may `mkdir ~/.bin`, add it to PATH before all other directories and use fresh `ld`.

But that way is weak, 'cause you will need update it manually every time you wish to update `ld`.

So, best way is to keep all users on server in their own chroots (that also increase security, 'cause your code separated from their and vice versa) and update `ld` in your chroot, when you need it.

Comment: Is there a way to know if we are in chroot ?

Comment: I think, you should check out this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14345/how-do-i-tell-im-running-in-a-chroot

Comment: BTW, I advise just update as it described in your question, unless you are totally sure, that other users need old `ld`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will replace the current version of ld

binutils package contains:
libc6 (>= 2.11)

zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)

so i think you need to update ld manually

Comment: The problem is that I can't find a binary and if I try to compile from source then I end up with "this linker was not configured to use sysroot"

Comment: even if you update ld i think this wont affect users that using it, am i right ?

Comment: I don't know, I hope so :)